# What are differences, or relationships, among "relative probability", "relative frequency", "probability density" and "probability"?

Tags: probability, distributions, terminology, histogram, frequency

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

What are the differences, or relationships, among

- "relative probability",
- "relative frequency",
- "probability density" and
- "probability"?

A simple example would help to better understand the differences and relationships among those terms.

As far as I understood, these terms are used to indicate/represent histograms and probability density functions (PDF), but I do not understand the exact relationship between those terms...

**EDITED PART: THE NEW QUESTION IS NOT RELATED TO THE OLD ONE, THEREFORE IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE (please review and re-open it - thank you for your collaboration!) In summary: I asked for relationships among quantities/terms, and not just for fragmented pieces of information. I need to see/establish/understand their connections.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Relative probability sounds a misnomer to me. Relative frequency is one flavour of probability. (Probabilities could be e.g. subjective or hypothetical if not based on empirical data.) Probability density is quite different, unless density is w.r.t. counting measure.

Comment: The key distinction to pay attention to is that probabilities are purely hypothetical: they can never be observed directly and almost never can be estimated exactly.  Note, too, that a probability *density* differs from a probability (in exactly the same way a mass density differs from a mass).  By searching our site you can see many examples.

Comment: Thanks both @NickCox and @whuber! It would be nice to put your two comments into a single answer, that I would accept....but it looks like it is already closed... :-)

Comment: Hello to everyone, I edited the question and I ask to re-open it, please. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I don't think there is much to say that has not already been said in reply to this and the previous question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Since connections are not clear yet to me, I think I will search for my answers somewhere else, even though it is tough, since textbooks repeat as parrots the same things  :-) Often,  mathematicians and statisticians make simple concepts extremely complicated to grasp... just by using unuseful jargon, as well as loose and blurry terminology..

Comment: I am not a mathematician or statistician, so am guilt-less in your terms. I can't recollect any mention of _relative probability_ in literature and never use it myself. In contrast _relative frequency_ seems to me useful terminology and the terminology _probability density_ was introduced precisely because probability density and probability are often quite different.

Comment: Your complaint often applies. Introductory textbooks are often lousy about explaining probability density: the two most common reasons are that authors don't understand the idea (this is often true in e.g. geography or geology or ecology) and (quite different) that they can't assume that readers have knowledge of calculus.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, very nice :-)